# What is the plural form of "weremoose"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number

From [The Kingdom of Loathing](http://www.kingdomofloathing.com) website:

> **The Pretty Good Escape**
>   Subject 37, in the Cobb's Knob Menagerie, wants
>   some spit from one of the weremooses on Level 2. He also wants to know
>   the right way to pluralize "weremoose."

Comment: The first thing I thought was "weremeese!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it is a word created simply for the purposes of that particular game, only the creator would know.  However, the plural of the word *moose* is ***moose***, as attested by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moose).

I would suggest ***weremoose*** would be the most likely answer to your question.